# I need Max Count in Sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with 3 columns:

```
A         B         C
test1     10
test1     15
test1     15
test2     1
test2     4
test2     3
test3     3
test3     3
test3     3
```

In the 3rd column I need `Count of Max(B) Row grouped on A`. Output should be:

```
A         B         C
test1     10        2
test1     15        2
test1     15        2
test2     1         1
test2     4         1
test2     3         1
test3     3         3
test3     3         3
test3     3         3
```

Comment: I don't like saying this, but what have you tried? can you show us your attempts at a solution and where you are struggling? As it stands, you're just asking  us to do the work without showing any efforts of your own.

Comment: Something to get you started, try using `COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY A,B)`

Comment: This is how I tried:  select [A],[B],COUNT(*)OVER(PARTITION BY [A],[B]) as C from #temp                                                                                test1  10 1
test1  15 2
test1  15 2
test2 3 2
test2  3 2
test2  4 1
test3  3 3
test3  3 3
test3  3 3

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( A VARCHAR(20), B INT, C INT )

INSERT  INTO @t
        ( A, B )
VALUES  ( 'test1', 10 ),
        ( 'test1', 15 ),
        ( 'test1', 15 ),
        ( 'test2', 1 ),
        ( 'test2', 4 ),
        ( 'test2', 3 ),
        ( 'test3', 3 ),
        ( 'test3', 3 ),
        ( 'test3', 3 )

UPDATE  t1
SET     C = ca.C
FROM    @t t1
        CROSS APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1
                                COUNT(*) AS C
                      FROM      @t t2
                      WHERE     t2.A = t1.A
                      GROUP BY  B
                      ORDER BY  C DESC
                    ) ca      

SELECT  *
FROM    @t
```

Output:

```
A       B   C
test1   10  2
test1   15  2
test1   15  2
test2   1   1
test2   4   1
test2   3   1
test3   3   3
test3   3   3
test3   3   3
```

Answer (score 0):

.
Hi there,

this could be a better solution then the already posted solution as it just need 1/3 of the cpu power/ram as it makes all in a batch instead of an indirect loop request.

```
-- Generate demo table
CREATE TABLE #temp(a nvarchar(20), b int, c int)

INSERT INTO #temp(a, b)
VALUES  (N'test1',10),
        (N'test1',15),
        (N'test1',15),
        (N'test2',1),
        (N'test2',4),
        (N'test2',3),
        (N'test3',3),
        (N'test3',3),
        (N'test3',3)
GO

-- Selecting the Result
SELECT t.a, t.b, mVal.c
FROM #temp as t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT gmax.a, COUNT(gmax.b) as c
    FROM (
            SELECT t.a, t.b, MAX(b) OVER(PARTITION BY t.a) as maxVal -- Get Maximum Value per group
            FROM #temp as t
        ) as gmax
    WHERE gmax.b = gmax.maxVal -- get only the necessary rows
    GROUP BY gmax.a
) mVal
        ON t.a = mVal.a


-- Updating into #temp
UPDATE t
SET c = mVal.c
FROM #temp t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT gmax.a, COUNT(gmax.b) as c
    FROM (
            SELECT t.a, t.b, MAX(b) OVER(PARTITION BY t.a) as maxVal 
            FROM #temp as t
        ) as gmax
    WHERE gmax.b = gmax.maxVal
    GROUP BY gmax.a
) mVal
    ON t.a = mVal.a

SELECT  *
FROM    #temp

DROP TABLE #temp
GO
```

Only the Select and maybe the update is relevant for you. The rest is just for demo purposes.

Best regards,
Ionic

Answer (score -1):

My approach is to use a corsure to `select distinct A and the max(B)`  from your table into `@A` , `@B group by  A`  this will come with results like :

```
A.          B.      
test 1.   15
test 2.    4 
test 3.    3
```

While the corsure Fitch's the data an loop
You can update your table

`set C =( select the count of A from your table  where A= @A  ) where A= @A`

I hop you got my idea .

Comment: Yes am sorry I mean cursor